# How to include concluding remarks in my paper

Tags: sectioning

I was wondering if there is some standard way of including a “concluding remarks” section in a LaTeX document. I couldn't find a specific environment to do this in (I was hoping there would be something similar to the `abstract` environment...), and keeping in mind that I have written a 20 page paper, organized in sections and subsections, neither of the following options really satisfies me:

1. Just adding a new section. This makes the most sense, but I only have other three sections in my paper, and they are all several pages long, while my concluding remarks occupy about a third of a page.
2. Adding a new subsection. Although this alternative doesn't have the problem of having a huge title for a small bit of text, it has the defect that the concluding remarks would seem to refer to the last section only, while my intention is that they should refer to the whole text.
3. Using the `abstract` environment and getting it to display "concluding remarks" instead of "abstract" (is it possible to do this? I tried adding `[optional arguments]`, but it didn't recognize them), but it wouldn't be at all standard.

Sorry if this isn't a standard LaTeX question, but I'd really like to organize my text properly, and I'm convinced there is an elegant way to do it. Perhaps one of the experienced LaTeX users on this website will be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: I'm not fond at all of "final remarks". Put them at the end of the introduction.

Comment: @egreg They really should go at the end, because they explicitly refer to things that came up throughout the whole text.

Comment: You can abuse the `abstract` environment with a `\def\abstractname{Concluding Remarks}` before it. But I wouldn't really recommend doing that (as I think it results in a very strange layout). I'd simply do a `\section` or `\section*`. From the reader's point of view this will give the most predictable result.

Comment: Also, the way the question is currently worded, I'm not sure it is on-topic here.

Comment: @Emilio So what? It's normal that the introduction refers to things that show up later. IMO, the "final abstract" is quite close to abomination. `;-)` If really you need those final remarks, write a section.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that's true, but my remarks aren't introductory comments. The paper is about Intuitionism in the Philosophy of Mathematics, and I would like to conclude with some considerations on how Intuitionism has failed to provide an acceptable solution to the foundational crisis; for these comments I need to make explicit reference to results which have come up throughout the text.

Comment: @Caramadir If you have suggestions on how to word this, and future questions better, I'm eager to know. Also, thaks for the edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All personal preferences aside, a modification of `\abstractname` allows you to print an `abstract` with whatever title you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{First section} \lipsum[2]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[3]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[4]

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Closing Remarks}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[5]
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

If you want more control over the closing remark layout and formatting, a copy of the existing `abstract` environment is possible, from which one can play around and make something to suit.

Comment: BTW if you *do* have any personal preferences and suggestions, I would be very interested!